# Bash Script to Back Up Backs Up Itself

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I have the following bash script that creates a tar.gz of my filesystem on a Kubuntu PC. The problem is, that it also tries to backup the tar.gz backup file, even though I am storing the backup in /tmp and omitting /tmp from the backup. I am wondering why it's backing up the file in /tmp even though I told it not to.

```
#!/bin/bash
# init

DATE=$(date +20%y%m%d)

sudo tar -cvpzf /tmp/`hostname`_$DATE.tar.gz \
--exclude=/proc \
--exclude=/lost+found \
--exclude=/sys \
--exclude=/mnt \
--exclude=/media \
--exclude=/dev \
--exclude=/tmp \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Desktop \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Documents \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Music \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Pictures \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Projects \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Roms \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/Videos \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/.VirtualBox\ VMs \
--exclude=/home/jlacroix/.SpiderOak \
/

scp /tmp/`hostname`_$DATE.tar.gz jlacroix@Pluto:/share/Recovery/Snapshots

sudo rm /tmp/`hostname`_$DATE.tar.gz
```

Comment: That's weird... it works for me when I try something similar to your example.

Are you seeing the /tmp/hostname_date.tar.gz file in the -v output from tar, or how do you know that it's being included?

Comment: Unrelated: Is there a particular reason you’re using `20%y` rather than `%Y`?

Comment: I watch the output, and see it in the process of backing up /tmp/hostname_date.tar.gz, so I CTRL+C to bail out.

I am using +20%y because I want the output to be 2012 instead of just 12.

Comment: @JayLaCroix %Y = 2012, %y = 12, although it's not a huge deal since either way it accomplishes your goal.  Just minutely cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "*" behind the excluded paths, how it works is the algorithm excludes the Pattern, not the directory.

So the pattern /home/jlacroix/Music != `/home/jlacroix/Music/*`

Give that a shot, works for me here.

**Edit**:
That still backs up the directory name, however.  So really you need it to look like this:

```
--exclude=/home/[username]/Music/* --exclude=/home/[username]/Music \
```

That would carry true for the remainder of items.

Comment: It's my fault! It turns out it wasn't backing up the archive, it was copying the archive to the server, and I mistook that for it copying the archive into the archive. Sorry!